# Substring to all td elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I'm generating with jsp values that I need to put it in a table but I need it shorter. I'm trying to reduce the value of the `<td>`. How can I do it with javascript I think I need to go through all the td items and reset the `text` property.

My code:

```
<c:if test="${not empty result.billedConsumptionActive.consumptionHour16}">
    <td class="bt_box n0 bw2 btl pad11 textTC textAllSmall">
        <c:out value="${result.powerFactor.consumptionHour16}"></c:out>
    </td>
</c:if>
```

My jQuery script:

```
$("td").text(function(i,v){
     return v.length > 5 ? v.slice(0, 5) : v
});
```

But it doesn't works. All the generated values disappear.

Comment: If you ate using jstl, there is a substring function. That way you don't need is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
$("td").each(function(index, el) {

   var v = $(this).text();


   v.length > 5 ? $(this).text(v.slice(0, 5)) : ''


});
```

Comment: You forgot to save new v value.

Comment: In this way it works but I'm using jstl so I think I'll use `<c:out value="${fn:substring(result.billedConsumptionReactive.consumptionHour01,0,5)}"></c:out>`